# TypeScript complaining about component missing properties which are injected by redux

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I am new to both typescript and Redux. I am using Redux to inject properties(state) into a component. When I render the component I don't pass it any props since they're injected by redux so it complains the props are missing.
When I hover over `<RelatedFilesTableContainer/>` I see the below error message. Thanks for any help!

> Exact Error: (TS) Type '{}' is missing the following properties from
> type 'IReportStore': showOrphaned, filters, filterFile

```
import * as React from "react";
import { RouteComponentProps } from "react-router";
import RelatedFilesTableContainer from "@Components/reportView/RelatedFilesTable";

type Props = RouteComponentProps<{}>;

const ReportPage: React.FC<Props> = () => {
    return <div>
        <RelatedFilesTableContainer />
    </div>;
}

export default ReportPage;
```

Component being rendered is below

```
import React from "react"
import { Container, Table } from "react-bootstrap";
import CheckBoxContainer from "@Components/reportView/Checkbox"
import ReportTableHeader from "@Components/reportView/ReportTableHeader";
import CollapsibleRow from "@Components/reportView/CollapsibleRow";
import * as reportStore from "@Store/reportStore";
import { withStore } from "@Store/index";

let renderCollapsibleRows = (filterFile: Object) => {
    let collapsibleRows = [];
    console.log(filterFile.RelatedFiles);
    filterFile.RelatedFiles.forEach(relatedFile => collapsibleRows.push(<CollapsibleRow rowData={relatedFile}/>));
    return collapsibleRows;
}

type Props = reportStore.IReportStore;
const RelatedFilesTable: React.FC<Props> = ({ filterFile }) => {
    return (
        <Container>
            <div className="d-flex justify-content-between">
                <p>{filterFile.FilterFileName}</p>
                <CheckBoxContainer />
            </div>
            <Table striped bordered hover>
                <ReportTableHeader />
                <tbody>{renderCollapsibleRows(filterFile)}</tbody>
            </Table>
        </Container>
    )
}

// Connect component with Redux store.
var RelatedFilesTableContainer = withStore(
    RelatedFilesTable,
    state => state.report, // Selects which state properties are merged into the component's props.
    reportStore.actionCreators, // Selects which action creators are merged into the component's props.
);

export default RelatedFilesTableContainer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want your `Props` definition to also include typings for props injected by redux (using the `withState` function). You can do this by breaking out separate `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` functions, and inferring `Props` based on this like so:

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state) => state.report;
const mapDispatchToProps = reportStore.actionCreators;

type Props = reportStore.IReportStore &
  ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps> &
  typeof mapDispatchToProps;

const RelatedFilesTable: React.FC<Props> = ({filterFile}) => { ... }

var RelatedFilesTableContainer = withStore(
  RelatedFilesTable,
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
);

export default RelatedFilesTableContainer;
```

Comment: This works to suppress the error message but I noticed I don't get autocomplete when destructuring Props anymore. In the store I have a property called "showOrphaned" which does not autocomplete when I have the props you mentioned here. Any ideas why?

Comment: Maybe check if your `Props` get inferred as `any`. This could be happening - if you haven't correctly typed `state` for example